# Restore Button On In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

my app reject reason "Restore Button On In-App Purchase"
how can add this button i use MKSKProduct v.4.0

thanks

Comment: provide more info about that

Comment: provide more info. What did you do when you got "Restore Button On In-App Purchase" message,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you have IAP within your app (that has products that can be restored), then you need to provide the user the ability to restore their original transactions (for example, if they buy a new  device).

You don't need MKStoreKit to do this, simple StoreKit will do the trick. Create your button where you need it to be, and hook it up to this method:

```
- (IBAction)restoreCompletedTransactions:(id)sender
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Check the documentation of `restoreCompletedTransactions` [on Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: but how do you apply this to ALL your view controllers w/ ads?